# java type generic: finding an example to show Function<? super E, ? extends F> is a better choice than Function<E, F>?

Tags: java, generics

There is class called Foo as following:

```
public class Foo<E> {

    private E val;

    public Foo(E val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public <F> Foo<F> map(Function<? super E, ? extends F> f) {
        Foo<F> res = new Foo<F>(f.apply(this.val));
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then, I call from main:

```
//Main.java
Foo<Integer> foo1 = new Foo<>(2);
Foo<String> foo2 = foo1.map(a -> a.toString());
```

My example in `Main.java` can also work with `Function<E, F>`. Could you give an example that can work only with `Function<? super E, ? extends F>`?